# Matlab RLC simulink and code help

Tags: passive-networks, matlab, simulink

In the circuit in the figure, the switch closes at time t = 0. What is the change of capacitor voltage and coil current in the range of 0-15 seconds? Show the solution in M. file and Simulink. 
Can you help me solve this question, please?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}\left(t\right)=2\text{V}_\text{L}'\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}'\left(t\right)=2\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\\
\\
20=\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{I}\left(0\right)=0\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)=4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Comment: I want matlab code i dont write code

Comment: @FurkanSNGR well I'm not giving you the Matlab code, use my equations and the solution can be found.